# How to tell using a guard statement if AVAudioPlayer has a file currently imported?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am looking for a statement like AVPlayer has available like audioPlayer.currentItem in an AVAudioPlayer, or at least a statement which can give me the same results - whether or not there is an audio file in the audioPlayer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is *always* "an audio file in the audio player". All of AVAudioPlayer's initializers require that you supply something for the audio player to play. This audio player couldn't exist, therefore, unless you had done that.

Perhaps the issue here is that you don't know whether you have in fact already initialized this reference to an audio player. The way to handle that is to make the reference an Optional and start it at `nil`:

```
var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer? = nil
```

When the time comes to configure the AVAudioPlayer, you do so, and now the reference is no longer `nil`:

```
self.audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(...)
```

The test you are looking for then boils down to `self.audioPlayer == nil`.